# How do I know the content of my 2-D array in MQL4?

Tags: mql4

I have got an array, **`s[7][7]`**, I read using a `ReadFileString()` a CSV file into it, the CSV file contained a set of numbers.

I'm looking for numbers greater than 85, stored in the 2-D array, and the column and row the number/element belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get content of the array just loop it over:

```
int value = 85;
for(int i=0; i<ArrayRange(s,0); i++){
   for(int j=0; j<ArrayRange(s,1); j++){
       if (StrToInteger(s[i][j])>value){
          // here you have i and j indexes of array
       }
   }
}
```

Of course you can have **`int array[][]`** instead of `string`-s for faster work, use `StrToInteger()` with `ReadFileString()` for that.

Comment: Thank you soo much!

Comment: If that helps - select as correct answer for others who might have same question!

Comment: Actually, I tried the code its outputting two elements instead of one- value 85!

Comment: Show what you have and how you got it. If you have two (or more) elements with value 85 - you need to decide whether any of them is fine or you need all (ie for the further investigation). 
In case any value above 85 is enough - `break;` ends that nearest for - loop, `return` exits from a function immediately.